流し方? What does it mean?
銃や懐刀、普通の人が入手できるものじゃない. それに自分と組み合った時の流し方、素人とは思えない軽やかさだった.
The character comment on a character personality. As far I can understand he's saying from the the fact he had a gun and a pocket knife, it meant he wasn't a normal person. Then he comment that one time they  formed a partnership, he was relaxed in a way it wouldn't make you think he was an amateur.
But what could 流し方 mean?

Here, 流す has a similar meaning to 受け流す, which means to dodge (an attack). So the character says that the opponent's way of dodging the character's attack is so light and relaxed that the opponent seems to be a pro.
